# Android CI/CD (Unit Test, SonarQube)

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube, pipeline, cicd

So I tried to implement CI/CD on my project.
And I got something i cant fix.
I'm using GitHub action.

I tried to run unit test.
This is my pipeline.

```
name: Java CI with Gradle

on:
push:
  branches: ["release", "staging", "pre_release"]
pull_request:
  branches: ["release", "staging", "pre_release"]

jobs:
 build:
 runs-on: windows-latest 

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Set up JDK 17
    uses: actions/setup-java@v3
    with:
      java-version: '17'
      distribution: 'temurin'
  - name: Run Unit Test
    run: |  
        .\gradlew.bat test  # Use gradlew.bat on Windows
```

I got this error:

> Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)

I tried to run SonarQube, and I got the same error.
Did any of you get this error ?
I found this issue on the Github runner repository too.
https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/2503
But that is still open.

Comment: Add step  - name: Setup Gradle
      uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2

Comment: @andreypc still not work on me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the gradle daemon heap and Kotlin compiler daemon heap.
https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/2503#issuecomment-1822250300